# JLabel panel opacity and general background coloring

Tags: java, swing, jframe, opacity

The idea behind the code is a simple multiplying game where it generates 2 numbers and I have to input the corret answer.

Basically, my question(s) is(are):

1. When I do operacao.setOpaque(false); it does nothing, or at least not what I'd expect it to do (http://puu.sh/pyVcE/813aa1843a.png - shouldn't the grey area be pink, since the background is pink?). Same happens with JLabels, the setOpaque(false) leaves a grey background behind the (in this case) numbers.
2. I have that last commented section because I saw someone around here saying to alter the paint method, and it did work, but caused some weird issues (painted over everything when I started the console, only the JTextField would be clear), and then I "fixed" it with the setOpacity(1); setBackground(pink); - is this a proper way of doing it?

---

```
 public class Frame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel panel, mensagem, operacao;
    private JTextArea sucesso;
    private JLabel numero1, numero2;
    private JTextField resposta;
    private Color pink = new Color(255, 213, 224);
    //more vars

    public Frame() {
        super("Jogo de Multiplicar!");
        setOpacity(1);
        setBackground(pink);

        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setSize(300, 200);

        panel = new JPanel();
        mensagem = new JPanel();
        operacao = new JPanel();
        mensagem.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        operacao.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        sucesso = new JTextArea();
        sucesso.setEditable(false);
        sucesso.setOpaque(false);
        sucesso.setFont(minhaFont2);

        Random randomGen = new Random();

        while (random1 == 0)
            random1 = randomGen.nextInt(10);
        while (random2 == 0)
            random2 = randomGen.nextInt(10);
        res = random1 * random2;

        numero1 = new JLabel();
        numero2 = new JLabel();
        numero1.setText(random1 + " *");
        numero2.setText(random2 + " =");
        numero1.setOpaque(false);
        numero1.setFont(minhaFont);
        numero2.setFont(minhaFont);

        resposta = new JTextField(2);
        resposta.addActionListener(new MinhaAcao());
        resposta.setFont(minhaFont);

        operacao.add(numero1);
        operacao.add(numero2);
        operacao.add(resposta);

        mensagem.add(sucesso);

        operacao.setOpaque(true);
        operacao.setBackground(pink);
        mensagem.setOpaque(true);
        mensagem.setBackground(pink);

        //add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(operacao);
        add(mensagem, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }/*
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(pink);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    }*/
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use sensible names for custom classes that don't mirror the names of core classes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to textfield to be pink. You may have to do this.

```
resposta.setOpaque(false);
```

I have refactored your code like below.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Frame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel panel, mensagem, operacao;
    private JTextArea sucesso;
    private JLabel numero1, numero2;
    private JTextField resposta;
    private Color pink = new Color(255, 213, 224);
    //more vars

    public Frame() {
        super("Jogo de Multiplicar!");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setSize(300, 200);
        getContentPane().setBackground(pink);
        panel = new TransperantPanel();
        mensagem = new TransperantPanel();
        operacao = new TransperantPanel();
        mensagem.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        operacao.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        sucesso = new JTextArea();
        sucesso.setEditable(false);

        Random randomGen = new Random();
        int random1 =0 , random2 = 0;   
        while (random1 == 0)
            random1 = randomGen.nextInt(10);
        while (random2 == 0)
            random2 = randomGen.nextInt(10);
        int res = random1 * random2;

        numero1 = new JLabel();
        numero2 = new JLabel();
        numero1.setText(random1 + " *");
        numero2.setText(random2 + " =");    


        resposta = new JTextField(2);
        resposta.setOpaque(false);
        resposta.addActionListener(new MinhaAcao());
        numero1.setFont(minhaFont);
        numero2.setFont(minhaFont);
        resposta.setFont(minhaFont);

        operacao.add(numero1);
        operacao.add(numero2);
        operacao.add(resposta);

        mensagem.add(sucesso);

        add(operacao);
        add(mensagem, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Frame f = new Frame();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    class TransperantPanel extends JPanel {

        public TransperantPanel() {
            setOpaque(false);
        }

    }
}
```

**What i have done is**

1. Setting background to contentPane of the frame.
2. Created a transparent panel(setting Opaque of the panel to false).
3. Setting JTextfield's Opaque to false.

Comment: Aye, that fixed it, thank you very much! Although, small questions, what is this new class doing different when comapred to, for example 
panel = new JPanel();
panel.setOpaque(false);
because I'm having trouble finding the difference. Maybe I just did something wrong the first time? Thanks anyway!

Comment: @ASDF it is not doing anything just avoid some boilerplate code. if suppose there are many panel which share same attributes.